# structure of serialized data in a MySQL database for SitePress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to edit some options from a WordPress installation. I located the fields in a serialized field in `wp_options`:

the value of field is in the following format:

```
a:93:{s:19:"hide_upgrade_notice";s:5:"3.3.5";s:25:"icl_capabilities_verified";b:1;s:21:"interview_translators";i:1;s:34:"existing_content_language_verified";i:1;s:25:"language_negotiation_type";s:1:"1";s:23:"theme_localization_type";i:1;s:14:"icl_lso_header";i:0;s:18:"icl_lso_link_empty";i:0;s:13:"icl_lso_flags";s:1:"1";s:19:"icl_lso_native_lang";i:0;s:20:"icl_lso_display_lang";i:0;s:18:"sync_page_ordering";i:1;s:16:"sync_page_parent";i:1;s:18:"sync_page_template";i:1;s:16:"sync_ping_status";i:1;s:19:"sync_comment_status";i:1;s:16:"sync_sticky_flag";i:1;s:13:"sync_password";i:1;s:17:"sync_private_flag";i:1;s:16:"sync_post_format";i:1;s:11:"sync_delete";i:0;s:15:"sync_delete_tax";i:0;s:20:"sync_post_taxonomies";i:1;s:14:"sync_post_date";i:0;s:21:"sync_taxonomy_parents";i:0;s:25:"translation_pickup_method";i:0;s:15:"notify_complete";i:1;s:26:"translated_document_status";i:1;s:17:"remote_management";i:0;s:15:"auto_adjust_ids";i:1;s:11:"alert_delay";i:0;s:12:"promo
```

How is this formatted? I know that this isn't valid JSON.
How can I edit/remove settings manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is PHP serialized data, a format that is largely unused now thanks to the prevalence of JSON. It was quite popular among PHP developers at one stage. It fell into disuse because there are some security concerns with php serialize and unserialize and also because of the rise of JSON. However it's still found in some apps.

use [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to convert to a php object

> unserialize — Creates a PHP value from a stored representation

Note: You haven't posted a valid serialized string (it's truncated)

Comment: Thanx. I had no idea about this function. I only json_encode and json_decode in my apps.

Comment: In case you need quick/ready serialized data search-replace functionality, you can use this tool too: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/